# A bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new to Java web developing and I am having a lot of trouble working with Hibernate. I looked at a lot of examples online on how to do this and so far I don't have any luck getting any of it to work. I notice some pattern they use online, a lot of them go like bellow.

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();

// do something with session

session.getTransaction().commit();
```

However, whenever I try to do that in my project, I got an error saying

```
Field sessionFactory in com.bT.practice.WebMySQLAspects.dao.StudentDAOImpl required a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found.
```

I am really confused about this and I couldn't find a good example on hibernate website on how to do this. I use `http://start.spring.io/` to bootstrap my app. Bellow is my code.

**ENTITY**

```
package com.bT.practice.WebMySQLAspects.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    public Student() {

    }

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }

}
```

**DAO IMPLEMENTATION**

```
 package com.bT.practice.WebMySQLAspects.dao;

 import java.util.List;

 import org.hibernate.Session;
 import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

 import com.bT.practice.WebMySQLAspects.entity.Student;

    @Repository
    public class StudentDAOImpl implements StudentDAO {
        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        @Override
        public List<Student> getStudents() {
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            List<Student> students = session.createQuery("from Student order by lastName").list();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            return students;
        }
    }
```

**SERVICE IMPLEMENTATION**

```
package com.bT.practice.WebMySQLAspects.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.bT.practice.WebMySQLAspects.dao.StudentDAO;
import com.bT.practice.WebMySQLAspects.entity.Student;

@Service
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentDAO studentDAO;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return studentDAO.getStudents();
    }

}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
package com.bT.practice.WebMySQLAspects.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.bT.practice.WebMySQLAspects.entity.Student;
import com.bT.practice.WebMySQLAspects.service.StudentService;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class StudentController {
    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    @GetMapping("/students/show")
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        List<Student> students = studentService.getStudents();
        return students;
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driverClssName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb_student_tracker?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
```

Comment: You are using spring, and you have a service annotated with `@Transactional` you don't need to start a transaction and commit it... Spring will already do it for you. Also, there is no need for a transaction in a simple sql query. Search what a database transaction is first, then, how spring handle database transaction... Understand things first then implement it.

Comment: oh sweet, thank you. but it didn't fix my issue though.

Comment: @dg2903 Have you made the reqiured entry for SessionFactory in bean xml

Comment: @AmanChhabra I do not have any bean.xml, if i understand correctly if I use annotation like ComponentScan and Component I shouldn't need bean.xml.

Comment: @AmanChhabra: This question is tagged with Spring Boot. Spring Boot creates the necessary beans automatically, there is no need to write bean definitions, let alone in XML.

Comment: @meriton In that case, doing data source configuration in JAVA class

Comment: hmmm so I looked at hibernate 5.0 and I saw them used EntityManagerFactory instead of SessionFactory. I changed my code to EntityManagerFactory and it worked, why? my Hibernate version is 5.2.17, they used SessionFactory in the 5.2 doc.

Answer (score 2):

Since hibernate has existed for nearly two decades now, many tutorials are horribly outdated. You'll have a far easier time if you use tutorials released in the last few years.

Originally hibernate could be accessed only in a hibernate specific way, using `Sessions` obtained from a `SessionFactory`. In 2006, the Java Persistence API standard created a general way of accessing object relational mappers in Java through `EntityManagers` obtained from an `EntityManagerFactory`. Its design was heavily influenced by the Hibernate team, and became the preferred way to access hibernate with the release of Hibernate 3.2 in the fall of 2006.

That is, the tutorials you found have been obsolete for over a decade. To see how it's done now, check out

- the Spring Team's tutorial [Accessing Data With JPA](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)
- and the [comprehensive documentation of Spring Data JPA](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jpa)